# Telegram bot on OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, telegram-bot

I have problem with https://core.telegram.org/bots.

1. Get token from BotFather.
2. Create self-signed ssl sertificate (https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed):

   openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"
3. Run server:

   openssl s_server -accept 88 -key YOURPRIVATE.key -cert YOURPUBLIC.pem
4. Send hook:

   curl -F "url=https://URL:88/bot" -F "certificate=@YOURPUBLIC.pem" https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook

Answer:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

5. Telegram connect to my server. Error:

   139690177754952:error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:s3_pkt.c:1257:SSL alert number 46
6. Test:

   openssl s_client -connect URL:88

OK. No problem.

How to:

1. Run openssl s_client ... as Telegram. Use -cert YOURPUBLIC.pem not work.
2. Fix this problems and recive data.

Comment: How did you get the Telegram log row (5° point)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need set real server name to sertificate CN, equal URL(4).

Comment: Thanks Mike! I become crazy about it! Your note SOLVED also my ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932007/telegram-bot-api-webhooks-self-signed-certificate-issue

Comment: If you use an IP instead of a DNS name, you must write an IP address without a port.

Comment: please how do you mean? i am stuck at this