# Telegram Bot API Webhooks Self-signed Certificate issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, telegram-bot

I'm working on a Ruby language server to manage multiple Telegram Bots via [setwebhooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)

BTW, I'll delivery the  server as opensource at [BOTServer](http://www.github.com/solyaris/BOTServer)

**PROBLEM**

I have troubles receiving webhook updates from Telegram Bot API Server. I have set a webhook token (Telegram reply "success") but I do not receive any update on the succesfully configured webhook.

I think the problem could be around [self-signed Certificate](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed) mysteries. See old [reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/3b4z1k/bot_api_recieving_nothing_on_a_correctly/) and answers.

I have similar problem and I fair the point is in some "misunderstanding" between Telegram Bot API Server that send HTTPs webhooks updates and the bot server receving webhooks (I use nginx as proxy/https SSL certificate handler).

It seems that someone solved the issue configuring nginx with a certificate "chain"; I'm pretty ingnorant in certificates tricks and so I ask:

**QUESTION**

May someone can post info, to configure nginx (any ssl web server!) with detailed settings / step-by step for dummies, showing how to pass from .key and .pem files described here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed to **set-up the certificate "chain"** to configure in nginx config, to be "accepted" by Telegram Bot API Server ?

BTW, my nginx config now:

```
upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

#
# HTTPS server
#
server {
  listen 8443 ssl;
  server_name myhost.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /mypath/ssl/PUBLIC.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /mypath/ssl/PRIVATE.key;

  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }
}
```

where PRIVATE.key + PUBLIC.pem files are that one generated following guidelines: [Using self-signed certificates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed):

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout PRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out PUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"
```

thanks

giorgio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answer myself, to share solution found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260827/1786393

the point was not the mentioned nginx configuration, but the PEM file:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"
```

**YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE** in the subj strig of openssl must be **real hostname** of your server that receive webhooks.

Comment: hmm, I don't get it !! generating the certificate `real hostname`as you say, but still no success. and I'm using a subdomain. does that make a difference?

Comment: I had success with domain.subdomain.com . After certificate generation Did you set webhook ? see step by step tutorial in my project www.github.com/solyaris/BOTServer

Comment: I did everything, but I still don't get requests from telegram. I did set webhook with my publickey and  I can call the webhook myself from browser (it works) but nothing comes from telegram.

Comment: SSL settings correctly configured in your webserver? Apache? Nginx ? Other ? See:  http://www.github.com/solyaris/BOTServer

Answer (score 1):

the solution that works for me:

I generated key pairs: `openssl genrsa -out webhook_pkey.pem 2048` and `openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key webhook_pkey.pem -out webhook_cert.pem`

don't forget to give FQDN name. give your host's ip at least

added it to nginx config

```
server {
    listen      8443 ssl;
    server_name MY_IP;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/myproject/tg_keys/webhook_cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/myproject/tg_keys/webhook_pkey.pem;

    location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/myproject/hb.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cURL options:

```
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = false
```